# Arithmetic progression and right angled triangle

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the sides of a right angled triangle are in Arithmetic progression then prove that their sides are in the ratio 3:4:5

I assumed the sides as x, x+d and x+2*d and started collecting the ratios of sides and I could not conclude

Comment: Use the Pythagorean Theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Consider three sides as $(a-d), a, (a+d)$

$\therefore (a-d)^2+a^2=(a+d)^2$(applying Pythagoras theorem, largest side is hypotenus)

will give you, $a=4d$

therefore the three sides are, $3d,4d,5d$, which are in the ratio $3:4:5$

Comment: Nice use of symmetry. Letting $a$ be the "middle" term, both in the case of three-term arithmetic sequences and geometric sequences, often simplifies the algebra.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Thank you Andre, I am very happy to receive appreciation from you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the first term $a$ and common difference $d$. Therefore, your sequence becomes:$$a,\ a+d,\ a + 2d$$

Now, these 3 terms form the sides of a right triangle. Since $a+2d$ is the largest (assuming d > 0), we can say that it is the hypothenuse.

Using the Pythagorean Theorem:

$$a^2 + (a+d)^2 = (a+2d)^2$$
$$a^2 + a^2 + 2ad + d^2 = a^2 + 4ad + 4d^2$$
$$3d^2 - a^2 + 2ad = 0$$
$$(3d-a)(d+a) = 0$$

Therefore, your solutions are $$3d = a$$ and $$d = -a$$

So if a = 3, d = 1. Therfore, one possible sequence is 3, 4, 5.

Similarly, if a = 6, then d = 2, so another possible sequence is 6, 8, and 10.

Answer (score 0):

If the sides are in AP (arithmetic progression), they will be $a,(a+d),(a+2d)$

Since, it is a right angled triangle, Using pythogoras theorem

$(a+2d)^2=a^2+(a+d)^2$

$a^2+4d^2+4ad=a^2+a^2+d^2+2ad$

$3d^2+2ad=a^2$

$a^2-3d^2-2ad=0$

$a^2-3ad+ad-3d^2=0$

$a(a+d)-3d(a+d)=0$

$(a-3d)(a+d)=0$

This gives $a=3d$ and $a=-d$

So the sides will become $3d,4d,5d$ or $3:4:5$